# Accessing a nested node in a json dictionary with an attribute

Tags: python, json, parsing

Note: I have previously asked a similar question but couldn't get any useful response.

I have to be able to parse the CountriesDictionary and for any given key such as "London", "Norway", "Sweden",  and other countries, I want to be able to he concatenation the "@myID" value with the respective "@myID" in the status node when I request the "key" such as "London" or "Norway".

1. For example #1: Currently my method can only do this: If I call my method, `getconcatenatedstring(CountriesDictionary , "London")`,
   I should get the result as `"35C.20C"`.

   To get the result, I have to concatenate the `@myID` of London which is `35C` with the @`myID` in the status node which is `20C`.
2. For example #2: My method cannot do this. Note: Norway is a nested node in London!

   If I call my method, `getconcatenatedstring(CountriesDictionary , "Norway")`,
   I should get the result as `"35C.12Q.20D"`.

   To get the result, I have to concatenate the `@myID` of London which is `35C` with the `@myID` in the Norway node which is `12Q` and finally the `@myID` of the status node in `InfoList` which is `20D`.
3. Example #3: My current method can get this output
   `getconcatenatedstring(CountriesDictionary , "Sweden")`, the output I should get is `"32C.15D"`.

To get the result, I need to concatenate the `@myID` of Sweden which is `32C` with the `@myID` in the status node of Sweden which is `15D`.

I have a json dictionary with the following information.

```
CountriesDictionary = {
  "Countries": {
    "London": {
      "@loc": "porch",
      "@myID": "35C",
      "Tid": "1",
      "InfoList": {
        "status": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "20C"
        },
        "count": {
          "@default": "0",
          "@myID": "1"
        }
      },
      "Norway": {
        "@loc": "backyard",
        "@myID": "12Q",
        "Tid": "2",
        "InfoList": {
          "status": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@myID": "20D"
          },
          "count": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@myID": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Sweden": {
        "@loc": "backyard",
        "@myID": "32C",
        "Tid": "2",
        "InfoList": {
          "status": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@myID": "15D"
          },
          "count": {
            "@default": "0",
            "@myID": "2"
          }
        }
      },
 // many more other countries with similar structure as above
  }
}
```

My method implementation. I am not sure what is missing in this method as I am unable to get the desired result for example #2 as described above.

```
def getconcatenatedstring(d, search_key):
    for k1, v1 in d.items():
        for k,v in v1.items():
            if k == search_key:
                print (k)
                return '{}{}.{}'.format(d['@myID'] + '.' if '@myID' in d else '',
                                            v['@myID'], v['InfoList']['status']['@myID'])

# Example call to method
getconcatenatedstring(CountriesDictionary, "Sweden")
```

Comment: just another version of the mentioned duplicate question (posted by OP previously)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have provided the method of implemetation. I am unsure why this function doesnt traveres it. :(

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest This question is not fully a duplicate as the previously asked question doesnt answer my question. I am unable to solve the bug and I am not so experienced in python unlike you who knows it better. Please do help me to resolve the issue. Thanks